# Is there a way on Android to determine if on LTE vs LTE Advanced network

Tags: android

In the Android SDK, there is a network type entry:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#NETWORK_TYPE_LTE

But this doesn't distinguish between LTE and LTE Advanced networks.

Is there some other way to check or tell the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is no portable official  way to distinguish `LTE` and `LTE-A` connections in `Android` applications.

But I've come into `NETWORK_TYPE_LTEA` network type in [Mediatek Android platform firmware sources](https://github.com/cslrcj/stuff/blob/master/SystemUI/src/com/mediatek/systemui/statusbar/networktype/NetworkTypeUtils.java), and it worked in my pet projects. 
There is also `NETWORK_TYPE_LTE_CA` network type in [`AOSP` sources](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/MobileSignalController.java) which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

However both these values are not documented in official `Android` documentation and it is unclear which versions support them.

Comment: I really wish the Android team had an official solution ;(